# Cannot implicitly convert type error on Android Spinner Tutorial

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Hi I am trying to do the Spinner Tutorial for the Android. 
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/spinner
I am getting the error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<Android.Widget.ItemEventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler<Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>' (CS0029)`
on line 26 of my Activity1.cs. I have just copied the code from the tutorial so I am not sure what I need to change this line to so I can run it.
Here is my Activity1.cs :

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace HelloSpinner
{
[Activity (Label = "HelloSpinner", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "Main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner);

        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs> (spinner_ItemSelected); 
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource (
            this, Resource.Array.planets_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

        string toast = string.Format ("The planet is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position));
        Toast.MakeText (this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to just use the delegate type declared by the event... ideally using the simpler method group conversion syntax:

```
spinner.ItemSelected += spinner_ItemSelected; 

...

private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
```

(Now you just need a using directive for `Android.Widget`.)

Comment: As additional info... the tutorial is most likely out of date - there were several changes to the event handling syntax for Mono for Android 4.2

Comment: When I replace line 26 with that I get the error: No overload for spinner_ItemSelected' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<Android.Widget.AdapaterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>'(CS0123)

Comment: That exact error - including `AdapaterView`? Seems a little odd... are you sure you changed the declaration of `spinner_ItemSelected` as I showed as well?

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice the change in the second line. I have changed both lines. Now I have an error: The type or namespace name "ItemSelectedEventArgs' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembky reference?). Do you know a using statement I should add.

Comment: @Elena: I hadn't realized that `ItemSelectedEventArgs` was a nested type. Editing...

Comment: It's Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs

Comment: @GregShackles: The problem is that it's a nested type (non-obviously).